# How to change animations used by animateLayoutChanges mechanism?

Tags: android, animation, layout

I have a `RecyclerView` in which user selects an item. Upon selection certain view becomes visible before the text (see image). I want to animate its appearance.

[image: Graphical representation]

`animateLayoutChanges` property on the item's layout does the job perfectly, except for the animation type for view appearance - it fades in. I want it to scale from 0 to 100% size, I believe it's called 'pop up' animation.

If I disable `animateLayoutChanges` and use XML animation for that, it works, but the nearby text is no longer animated (it should slide to accomodate space for the view and its margin). It instantly shifts to the right and then animation is played. This is worse with reverse animation, since the text overlaps the view before it has disappeared.

So I need to combine default mechanism and my own animation somehow.
What would be the simplest way to accomplish that without delving into custom animations?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

After much digging in the wrong places, found the answer myself. Might help somebody.

`animateLayoutChanges` property if enabled utilizes an instance of `LayoutTransition` to do its job in `ViewGroup`.

So in order to change animations, you can create an instance of `LayoutTransition`, set `Animator` for the transition that you need to change and then assign that instance to `ViewGroup` via `setLayoutTransition()`.

In my case the result is:

```
Animator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((Object)null, PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1, 0), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1, 0));
scaleDown.setDuration(300);
scaleDown.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());

Animator scaleUp = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder((Object)null, PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0, 1), PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0, 1));
scaleUp.setDuration(300);
scaleUp.setStartDelay(300);
scaleUp.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());

LayoutTransition itemLayoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
itemLayoutTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, scaleUp);
itemLayoutTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, scaleDown);

ViewGroup av = (ViewGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.animated_layout);
av.setLayoutTransition(itemLayoutTransition);
```

More info in [LayoutTransition reference documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html).

Comment: Can you please show full code for this? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's actually been a while since I last coded for Android, but still, managed to dig it up from my archives :) if you're familiar with RecyclerView (from android.support.v7 library) this gist should help you: https://gist.github.com/mrnateriver/cd988f6ca745ebad7db7cc16581069ee it's not a full implementation of RecyclerView.Adapter, but it should give you an idea how custom animations work

Comment: I was hoping for a solution of a normal layout (LinearLayout, for example)

Comment: In order to make this example work, you need to pass instance of view (which is need to be animated) instead of null to the call `(ofPropertyValuesHolder((Object) null` – replace `(Object) null` with your `view`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do same thing with animateLayoutChange just see following article

https://proandroiddev.com/the-little-secret-of-android-animatelayoutchanges-e4caab2fddec

Answer (score 2):

I found that i can set animation type and duration this way

```
rootLayout.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
rootLayout.layoutTransition.setDuration(3000)
```

Where rootLayout - is layout, where animationLayoutChanges = true